# Working with value constructors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, value-constructor

I'm quite stuck in this exercise, the program should receive an input like:

```
dividing (Number 50) (Number 10)
```

And then output something like:

```
Number 10
```

---

I tried this:

```
data Number = Ok Double | Error String deriving Show

dividing :: Number -> Number -> Number
dividing (Number num1) (Number num2) = (Ok (num1/num2))
```

But I'm getting this errors on terminal:

```
35.hs:288:10: error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Number’
35.hs:288:24: error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Number’
```

---

The most approximate working code that I got was the code below, but the user has to input Ok or Error to make the operation, what is a real workaround:

```
data Number = Ok Double | Error String deriving Show

dividing :: Number -> Number -> Number
dividing (Ok num1) (Ok num2) = (Ok (num1/num2))
dividing (Ok num1) (Error "0") = (Error ("You can't divide by zero"))
```

I would like to know a better way to receive Numbers directly instead of receiving the value constructors.

Comment: Pattern match against `(Ok 0.0)` before you match against `(Ok num2)`. That should cover the special case.  Don't match against `(Error "0")` but a general `(Error e)` - think about the case `dividing (Ok 23.0) (dividing (Ok 42.0) (Ok 0.0)))` and what should happen to the `Error ("You can't divide by zero")` that is produced in the inner application.

Comment: No, there is no better way to receive Numbers directly instead of receiving the value constructors. The value constructors *are* the Numbers.

Comment: If *one* argument is an error, you just need to propagate that as the return value. If *both* arguments are errors, it's not clear if you should propagate one or the other error, or if you are expected to combine them into a *new* `Error` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with `Ok` and `Error`? You want to create the number data constructor, so just name it `Number`:

```hs
-- "Number" on the left signifies the number type
-- "Number" on the right signifies the number data constructor
data Number = Number Double deriving (Show)

dividing :: Number -> Number -> Number
-- division by 0 doesn't need to be handled since it's Infinity by the floating point standard
dividing (Number a) (Number b) = Number (a / b)
```

Comment: Thank you! But this exercise is requiring to work with Ok and Error, to return Error when the pattern matching get 0 in the second argument. But I'm really stuck on this...

Comment: @LuanTorres If `Ok` and `Error` are required, but the test case uses `(Number 50)` there's something wrong. Either you are misreading your exercise, or who wrote it made a mistake. If this is an assignment, re-read it carefully. If you are still convinced you need the `Ok` and `Error` value constructors, but the test should use `Number 50`, contact your instructor asking if there might be a typo in the test case, and they actually meant `Ok 50`.